# Using an echo inside a shortcode function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a Wordpress plugin to display a Google News feed of the post's tags.

I'm trying to put this:

```
<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_tag_list('','+','')); ?>
```

into the single quotes of the Google URI of this echo:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[hungryfeed url="https://news.google.com/news/feeds?q='[[above function here]]'&output=rss" template="1" max_items="1"]' ); ?>
```

I'm not particularly proficient in PHP; can anyone advise of the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your first code into a variable then put the variable into the url. Something like this might work

```
<?php

$tags = strip_tags(get_the_tag_list('','+',''));
echo do_shortcode('[hungryfeed url="https://news.google.com/news/feeds?q='.$tags.'&output=rss" template="1" max_items="1"]');

?>
```

Comment: Perfect! I had originally fiddled with using a variable, so it's nice to see the correct way to do it. I just re-added in the echo before do_shortcode.